# Postgres join and count multiple relational tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join the 2 tables to the first table and group by a vendor name. I have three tables listed below.

`Vendors Table`

```
| id         |      name 
|:-----------|------------:|
| test-id    | Vendor Name |
```

`VendorOrders Table`

```
| id         | VendorId    | Details      | isActive(Boolean)| price |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:| -----------------| --------
| random-id  |   test-id   |  Sample test |   TRUE            | 5000
```

`OrdersIssues Table`

```
| id         | VendorOrderId| Details.   |
|:-----------|--------------:-----------:|
| order-id   |   random-id  | Sample test|
```

The expected output is to count how many orders belong to a vendor and how many issues belongs to a vendor order.

I have the below code but it's not giving the right output.

````
SELECT "vendors"."name" as "vendorName", 
COUNT("vendorOrders".id) as allOrders,
COUNT("orderIssues".id) as allIssues 
FROM "vendors" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "vendorOrders" ON "vendors".id = "vendorOrders"."vendorId" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "orderIssues" ON "orderIssues"."vendorOrderId" = "vendorOrders"."id"
GROUP BY "vendors".id;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the keyword `DISTINCT`, at least for `allOrders`:

```
SELECT v.name vendorName, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT vo.id) allOrders,
       COUNT(DISTINCT oi.id) allIssues 
FROM vendors v
LEFT OUTER JOIN vendorOrders vo ON v.id = vo.vendorId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderIssues oi ON oi.vendorOrderId = vo.id
GROUP BY v.id, v.name;
```

Consider using aliases instead of full table names to make the code shorter and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, any idea how I can also count orders that isActive=true to use the alias "activeOrders"?

Comment: @dealwap Try: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN vo.isActive THEN vo.id END) activeOrders`.

Comment: On this same table, what if I need to sum up a `price` column? note that I can't use DISTINCT because different table might have the same values. Any idea?

Comment: In a query with multiple joins the result may contain duplicate rows for the price that you want to sum. So just SUM(price) may return the wrong result. Post a question with sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining along two related dimensions.  The overall number of rows is the number of issues.  But to get the number of orders, you need a distinct count:

```
SELECT v.*, count(distinct vo.id) as num_orders,
       COUNT(oi.vendororderid) as num_issues
FROM vendors v LEFT JOIN
     vendorOrders vo
     ON v.id = vo.vendorId LEFT JOIN
     orderIssues oi
     ON oi.vendorOrderId = vo.id
GROUP BY v.id;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Quoting column and table names makes the query harder to write and read.  Don't quote identifiers (you may need to recreate the tables).
- Postgres support `SELECT v.* . . . GROUP BY v.id` assuming that the `id` is the primary key (actually, it only needs to be unique).  This seems like a reasonable assumption.